# FIREBASE NO MUESTRA MI PROYECTO

Tags: firebase, deployment

Acabo de hacer el deploy de una  app pero al abrir la pagina de mi proyecto en firebase no me aparece lo que yo hice , solo veo esta imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que puede estar pasando?? funciona bien en los tutoriales que vi, segui los pasos igual, pero no se que tiene .

Comment: de un poco de mas información, por ejemplo las tecnologías con las que esta trabajando, y si la aplicación  esta alojada cerca de la raíz, que has intentado hacer

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque esta pregunta no se relaciona con programación

Comment: @JacksonQuintero encontre el error, estaba trabajando con angular en vscode y el error fue al empezar el deploy, no lo hice en la carpeta del proyecto, si no en la carpeta madre por eso se subio como si estuviera vacio. Muchas Gracias .

Answer (score 0):

**Hola,** espero esto te ayude con tu proyecto.

> Sucede que al hacer deploy en firebase, por defecto se encuentra deployando apuntando hacia el html que te proveen ellos.
> Por ejemplo aqui te muestro, en mi caso yo tengo que decirle a firebase que mi proyecto esta dentro de /dist/my-store. *flecha rosa*

[image: Dist]

> Entonces en tu proyecto con firebase vas a tener 'firebase.json' aqui encontraras la configuracion. Fijate que donde dice "public" por defecto viene index, cambialo y vuelve a deployar. Saludos !

[image: firebasejson]

¡¡Exitos ☆*: .｡. o(≧▽≦)o .｡.:*☆!!